# Count column if it contains a filled cell in Excel

Tags: excel, count, return-value

This is a simple question, but I cannot find the answer anywhere.

So, let's say I have range `A1:D20`, with at least one value in columns A and C. The number of columns with at least one filled cell is therefore 2.

How do I get a formula to count the number of columns within a range that contain at least one value? I would also like to count columns with criteria, but that's of secondary importance at the moment.

I have a large range of at least 35 columns, so a shorter expression would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure a good search would have given you more result than nothing, but try below:

```
=IF(COUNTA("A1:A20")>0,1,0)+IF(COUNTA("B1:B20")>0,1,0)+IF(COUNTA("C1:C20")>0,1,0)+IF(COUNTA("D1:D20")>0,1,0)
```

**EDIT**

Well, I guess if you want to work without any helper rows to use the COUNTA funtion a smooth way could be a UDF, possibly like so:

```
Function CountColumns(RNG As Range) As Long

Dim COL As Range
For Each COL In RNG.Columns
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(COL) > 0 Then CountColumns = CountColumns + 1
Next COL

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. That works, but I have 35+ columns, something I should have mentioned, and I have more than one datasheet, so I would rather not adjust the resulting larger formula every time. Is there a shorter method?

Comment: With helper rows, you might want to look into an UDF (see updated answer)

Comment: That is beautiful. Thank-you very much.